# Converting a PDF file to HTML file using PHP

Tags: php, html

How can I convert a PDF file to HTML file using PHP. I have also tried with some libraries, but it didn't work.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named [ask] and [mcve]. And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922).

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

**1)** Download and unpack the .exe file to a folder: **http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdftohtml/**

**2)** Create a .php file, and put this code (assuming, that the pdftohtml.exe is inside that folder, and the source `sample.pdf` too):

```
<?php
$source_pdf = "sample.pdf";
$output_folder = "MyFolder";

if (!file_exists($output_folder)) { 
    mkdir($output_folder, 0777, true);
}

$a= passthru("pdftohtml $source_pdf $output_folder/new_file_name", $b);
var_dump($a);
?>
```

**3)** Enter **MyFolder**, and you will see the converted files (depends on the number of pages..)